# rails4 - capistrano3 : How to start-stop-restart redis-server after deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, capistrano3

I am trying to add a start-stop-restart recipe for the redis-server

logged in the remote server via ssh I can run

```
 service redis-server restart
```

but adding to deploy.rake

```
%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
  desc "#{command} Redis server."
    task command do
      on roles(:app) do
       execute "service redis-server #{command}"
      end
    end
end
```

I get an error on restart

```
 DEBUG [8410afb7] Command: service redis-server restart
 DEBUG [8410afb7]   Stopping redis-server:
 DEBUG [8410afb7]   redis-server.
 DEBUG [8410afb7]   Starting redis-server:
 DEBUG [8410afb7]   touch:
 DEBUG [8410afb7]   cannot touch ‘/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid’:  
 Permission denied
```

which is obvious as /run is root:root...
how  can I solve it ?  should I install redis-server in my home directory ? ( if possible? )

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I should write :

```
    execute :sudo, "service redis-server #{command}"
```

in my deploy.rake recipe